# i have href link in jsp page and destination page shows script code if hacker add the script to href

Tags: java, jsp, auditing

first page is like this:

```
<a href = "javascript:test('abcd.jsp?asd=<%= asd 
%>');">
function test(x)
    { 
        document.abc.method='post';
        document.abc.action=x;
        document.abc.submit();
    }
```

hacker adds some script `"><script>alert(12345)</script>">` code to url then submit it abcd.jsp display the alert msg which is written in script code.

Comment: So ??? What you are going to do ? I mean ,what is your question?

Comment: @ sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ i don't want to display script on next page.

Comment: What is that asd? are you taking input from user?

Comment: @RajavelD yes it is input

Comment: @sureshmanda I have tried with this, but alert is not coming